# I got a thicker line at my CV

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I designed a CV in Photoshop yesterday, but when I exported the pages, I got this result.

On the second page, the baseline is thicker then what it is in Photoshop.

This is what it looks like when exported to a pdf.

[image: On Chrome PFD]

And This is what it looks like inside Photoshop.

[image: On PS]

I can't get the thick line to appear unless I zoom into a certain level.

[image: Zoomed into a level]

I'm not sure what the problem is and I have never faced an issue like this before.

### EDIT

---

After reading the answers I have decided to create the whole document in Illustrator or In Design.

Thank you for all of your attention.

Also, I'm not very skilled and I just listed the programs that I familiar with. Most of the agencies in my country don't use them for highly skilled applications yet they are always searching for someone who has 2 years of experience.

I'm looking to impress them with my CV so that is why I added them.

Comment: Why are you using Photoshop?   It's not designed for work like this - in fact I would go so far as to say it's totally inappropriate to use Photoshop to create a CV.  Use something else, like InDesign, Scribus, even MS Word.

Comment: Good advise. I'm not flexible at MS Word but in In Desgin I might have some chance to re create it

Comment: Design it in Illustrator? Export to pdf? Also as a note, it's bad form to have "skill bars"/images on a resume.

Comment: The CV format expectations may of course be highly localised...

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I can’t speak for Turkey because I’ve never worked there, but around these parts, it’s perfectly commonplace and not at all a problem to list your skills on a resume. If it’s for a job application, they’re _expected_, and recruiters would be puzzled by their absence. Also nothing wrong with images on a resume, provided they fit and make sense (as these little logos definitely do).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was talking about "skill bars" not skills in general. Re-read my comment. In general, it's bad form to have images on a resume that cause clutter and don't add to the clarity or visibility of the skills being presented. When hiring I almost always once-over and  just toss out resumes with images or like this one: https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-images-plus1/einancunlu-resume-1.png

I generally find that they contain weak work history and use the imagery to distract and cover that up.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I dont make a list of programs i know how to use simply because the list is so long.  Also me not including microsoft office makes HR puzzled, i usually need to answer that i know how to use excel, but i dont count myself skilled in it as i only use it when other people ask me how to do something with it and that the only time i use word is when i am ordered to, like in my thesis.

Comment: actually not my business, but ... Think, if some day someone wants to hire a person with perfect knowledge and skills around Adobe software  and makes just for more info a search for "Özberk Akbaş" . Then he finds and reads this.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor What in the images do you mean by ‘skill bars’, then? I don’t see any of what I would call skill bars…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do this in Illustrator

You should be creating this in a vector program, not a raster one. That being said, Acrobat has known issues of drawing elements, text etc. with incorrect widths and weights.

Try zooming in an out and see if it still occurs.

Try exporting to different formats and see if the results vary.

Overall a lot of your headache can be avoided by using the optimal program to create the CV in the first place; Illustrator.